# mysql search events between dates?

Tags: mysql, sql

i have a little problem in sql query, i want to display some events which are in between two given (start and end) dates, i did better to retrieve events between dates like,

```
SELECT event_id, event_name
FROM events
WHERE start_date >= 2013-07-16 AND end_date <= 2013-07-30
```

but i am facing problem to retrieve events ,

1=> those are starts before my start_date and ends before my end_date

2=> those are starts before my end_date and ends after my end_date

3=> those starts before my start_date and ends after my end_date

All these three lies in between these dates, i am confused about the query, please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine Whether Two Date Ranges Overlap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/325933/determine-whether-two-date-ranges-overlap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is simple really:

```
SELECT event_id, event_name
FROM events
WHERE start_date <= 2013-07-30 AND end_date >= 2013-07-16
```

(Note that I flipped the dates)